# I have checklistBox and I want to get the selected item's valuememebr and display member c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

I have a checklistbox where users can select multiple items, I have to go through the whole list and check the checked items:

```cs
foreach (var itemChecked in chklistCurrency.CheckedItems)
{
    var row = (itemChecked as DataRowView)?.Row;
    // ...
}
```

I tried to use datarowview and datarow alone it gives me error in Null value reference

Here is my another code but Value and DisplayMember are in redline

```cs
foreach (var itemChecked in chklistCurrency.CheckedItems)
{
    var cra = new CurrencyAccount();
    cra.CurrencyName = itemChecked.ValueMember;
    cra.CurrencySymbol = itemChecked.DisplayMember;  
    // ...
}


DataSource of the checklist was inserted like this 

   var currency = db.currencies.ToList();
            foreach (var item in currency)
            {
                chklistCurrency.DisplayMember = item.currencyName;
                chklistCurrency.ValueMember = item.currencySymbol;                
                chklistCurrency.Items.Add(item.currencyName);
            }
```

Comment: Show how you set the DataSource of your CheckedListBox. Is it actually a DataTable? Is it a Custom Control?

Comment: i updated the code, I didnt use datatble , assigned the ValueMember and DisplayMember to each item, Now I want to retrieve the Value and Dispaly Member

Comment: You cannot try to get a DataRowView from something that is not. You have added strings to your CheckedListBox. Setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` is pointless. Set the `currency` List as DataSource (with a CheckListBox, you have to set the DataSource first, then `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`). Each Item in the CheckedListBox is then one of the objects that the `currency` List contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checklistbox sourse data code

```
   string mainconn = (helper.CnnVal("poscon"));
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "select currencyName,currencySymbol from [dbo].[currency]";
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            this.chklistCurrency.DataSource = dt;
            ((System.Windows.Forms.ListBox)chklistCurrency).DisplayMember = "currencyName";
            ((System.Windows.Forms.ListBox)chklistCurrency).ValueMember = "currencySymbol";
```

retrieving the checked item with this code

```
  foreach (var itemChecked in chklistCurrency.CheckedItems)
                {
                    currencyaccount cra = new currencyaccount();
                    var row = (itemChecked as DataRowView).Row;                    
                    cra.currencyName = row.Field<string>("currencyName");
                    cra.currencySymbol = row.Field<string>("currencySymbol");
                    cra.accountId = at.accountId;
                    db.currencyaccounts.Add(cra);
                    db.SaveChanges();                       
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this.

```
foreach(var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{   
     DataRowView row = (item as DataRowView).Row;
     currencyaccount cra = new currencyaccount();
     cra.currencyName = row["currencyName"];
     cra.currencySymbol = row["currencySymbol"];  
}
```

Comment: what is the mistake? And you should be ensure for currencyName and currencySymbol columns

Comment: cannot convert datarow to  datarowview and red underline after the equal for all , I had updated the datasource code if it can help

Comment: can you change this line 
`DataRowView row = (item as DataRowView).Row; `
to `DataRow row = (item as DataRowView).Row;`

Answer (score 1):

The following focuses on providing a list of checked items from a `CheckedListBox` with a DataTable as the DataSource.

[Project](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version1/SqlServerAsyncReadCore) in GitHub repository (done in C#9 but the extensions are from .NET Framework meaning they work in any version of the .NET Framework).

Snippet for select statement

```
#region So there is no guessing when working with data in the form
/// <summary>
/// Product table primary key <see cref="ReadProductsTask"/>
/// </summary>
public static readonly string PrimaryKey = "ProductID";
/// <summary>
/// What to display in CheckedListBox
/// </summary>
public static readonly string DisplayColumn = "ProductName";
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Responsible for reading products in 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string SelectStatement()
{
    return $"SELECT P.{PrimaryKey}, P.{DisplayColumn}, P.SupplierID, S.CompanyName, P.CategoryID, " +
           "C.CategoryName, P.QuantityPerUnit, P.UnitPrice, P.UnitsInStock, P.UnitsOnOrder, " +
           "P.ReorderLevel, P.Discontinued, P.DiscontinuedDate " +
           "FROM  Products AS P INNER JOIN Categories AS C ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID " +
           "INNER JOIN Suppliers AS S ON P.SupplierID = S.SupplierID";
}
```

Class for obtaining checked items

```
public class ProductItem    
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => ProductName;
}
```

Extension method for obtaining checked items

```
public static List<ProductItem> ProductSelectedList(this CheckedListBox sender, string primaryKeyName)
{
    return
    (
        from item in sender.Items.Cast<DataRowView>()
            .Select(
                (data, index) =>
                    new ProductItem
                    {
                        Index = index,
                        Identifier = data.Row.Field<int>(primaryKeyName),
                        ProductName = data.Row.Field<string>("ProductName")

                    }
            )
            .Where((x) => sender.GetItemChecked(x.Index))
        select item
    ).ToList();
}
```

Form code to load CheckedListBox in form Shown event

```
DataTable table = await DataOperations.ReadProductsTask(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);

ProductCheckedListBox.DataSource = table;
ProductCheckedListBox.DisplayMember = DataOperations.DisplayColumn;
```

Button Click event to get checked items

```
private void GetCheckedProductsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<CheckedListBoxExtensions.ProductItem> results =
        ProductCheckedListBox.ProductSelectedList(DataOperations.PrimaryKey);

    if (!results.Any()) return;
    StringBuilder builder = new();

    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        builder.AppendLine($"{item.Identifier}, {item.ProductName}");
    }

    textBox1.Text = builder.ToString();

}
```

Screenshot

[image]